# Error 1064 while trying to execute stored procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie in SQL and now I'm trying to execute dynamic stored procedure ( wrote it using phpmyadmin). Previously I've created a DB called Store and Products table inside. When I try to execute it with 'Electricity' value I get a syntax error you can see in the screenshot below . I tried to add @ to passed parameter and got unknown column error. Anyone can explain what I am doing wrong ?

Update :

```
BEGIN  

SET @request_string = "SELECT * from Products WHERE 1";
If(category IS not null )
  Then SET @request_string = @request_string + ' AND @Category=?';
end if;
SET @Category= category;
PREPARE statement from @request_string;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END
```

Error :

```
The following query has failed : "SET @p0 = 'Electricity' ; CALL 'spGetProductsList(@p0);".

MySQL said #1064 - you have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1.
```

UPDATE :

The problem was solved after P.Salmon reply

Now my 4th line looks like this :

```
Then SET @request_string = CONCAT(@request_string,' AND @Category= category');
```

Comment: the error msg is not enough  post your code   a as  text  and  avoid  img only post 
 .. so post as text your error msg too

Comment: Replace screenshot with procedure text (as text!). Add error message text (as text too!).

Comment: And remember about DELIMITER reassign.

Comment: + in mysql is an arithmetic operator use concat for erm string concatenation

Comment: P.Salmon you were right that was the problem . For some reason I can't upvote and accept your answer ( maybe because I don't have enough reputation ? ).  Small off-top : if I leave my 4th line like in the last update does it mean I'm protected from SQL INJECTION ( assuming I use prepared statement ) ?